# Django: how to make POST request with form data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm learning Django and am running into an issue posting a piece of data to the database.  Here's my code:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    ...
    path("listing/<int:listing_id>", views.display_listing, name="listing")
]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usr_bids')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    bids = models.ManyToManyField(Bid, blank=True, related_name='bids')    
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class BidForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ['price']
```

**views.py**

```
def display_listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
       
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        if request.POST.get("button") == "Watchlist":
            if not user.watchlist.filter(listing=listing):
                watchlist = Watchlist()
                watchlist.user = user
                watchlist.listing = listing
                watchlist.save()
            else:
                user.watchlist.filter(listing=listing).delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(listing.id, )))
        if not listing.closed:
            if request.POST.get("button") == "Close":
                listing.closed = True
                listing.save()
            else:
                price = float(request.POST["price"])
                bids = listing.bids.all()
                if user.username != listing.creator.username:
                    if price <= listing.price:
                        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html',{
                            'listing': listing,
                            'form': BidForm(),
                            'message': 'Increase your bid.'
                        })
                    form = BidForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        bid = form.save(commit=False)
                        bid.user = user
                        bid.save()
                        listing.bids.add(bid)
                        listing.price = price
                        listing.save()
                    else:
                        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
                            'form': form
                        })

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(listing.id, )))
    else:
        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
            'listing': listing,
            'form': BidForm(),
            'comments': listing.comments.all()
        })
```

**auction/listings.html**

```
<div>
<form action="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bid">{{ listing.bids.count }} bid(s) so far.  You have the best bid!.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Bid">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I populate a value (e.g. 300) in the price field.  Then, I click the "Send Bid" button.  Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Does anyone see why I'm unable to save a price to the database?  Thanks in advance for taking a look!

Comment: Try to add `form.save()` after `listing.save()`

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, you should rather have something like:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}

    <input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Bid">
</form>
```

in your template.